# How to add packages in tikz using R

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, r

I wrote the following commands in *R* to generate a picture. However, the y-axis label is missing as the picture below shows. There seems to be some error in `ylab="$\\ln \\mathbb V \\widehat\\sigma_{MOP, \\alpha}$"`. However, I could not figure out why. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

> Error: 
>       TeX was unable to calculate metrics for the following string
>       or character: $\ln \mathbb{V} \widehat{\sigma}_{MOP, \alpha}$

```
var.asym <- function(shape, alpha){
  0.001*shape*shape*alpha*(1-alpha)^(2*shape-1)/(1-(1-alpha)^shape)^2
}

tikz("MOPasyvar.tex", width=4, height=3)
par(mar=c(4, 4, 0.5, 0.2))
theta0 <- c(-0.4, 1)
plot(seq(0.001, 0.999, by=0.001), log(var.asym(theta0[1], seq(0.001, 0.999, by=0.001))), type="l", lwd=2, ylim=c(-8, 0),
     xlab="$\\alpha$", ylab="$\\ln \\mathbb V \\widehat\\sigma_{MOP, \\alpha}$")
theta0 <- c(0.4, 1)
lines(seq(0.001, 0.999, by=0.001), log(var.asym(theta0[1], seq(0.001, 0.999, by=0.001))), lty=2, lwd=2)
legend("top", legend=c("$\\xi_0=-0.4$", "$\\xi_0=+0.4$"), lty=c(1, 2), lwd=2, bty="n")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Er... what did you write them *in* exactly? This is not from a `.tex` file, is it? Also, any error in particular or just some error in general? Please remember that we only know what you tell us right now as our crystal balls are all out for repair in the summer season.

Comment: Er... Sorry. I do not know what you meant. I wrote the above codes in R.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I wrote them in a `.tex` file as in `tikz("MOPasyvar.tex", width=4, height=3)`.

Comment: That is rather important information. I'm glad to see you've edited your question accordingly. (So you presumably *did* know what I meant.)

Comment: Probably you are missing packages required for one or more of the symbols you're using.

Comment: You need to tell `TikZdevice`  to load the `amsfonts` package, because you are using `\mathbb` in your y label.  Try adding `options( tikzLatexPackages =c(getOption( "tikzLatexPackages" ),"\\usepackage{amsfonts}"))`

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. I could not figure out how to tell `tikz ` the right package to use.

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you are using `\mathbb` in your y label, and the `mathbb` fonts require some math font to be loaded.  In this case, `amsfonts` will do the trick, so you have to tell `TikZdevice` to load that package.  To do that use:

```
options(tikzLatexPackages 
   =c(getOption( "tikzLatexPackages" ),"\\usepackage{amsfonts}"))
```

You can add as many packages as needed separated by commas (since this is simply a `c()` function.)

Comment: What if I need more than one package? Can I simply add their names like `"\\usepackage{amsfonts}", "\usepackage{whatever}"`?

Comment: @LaTeXfan Yes. I've updated the answer.